# External (Thunderbolt 2) drive keeps changing to read-only randomly

Tags: hard-drive, mojave, thunderbolt

I'm running macOS 10.14.2 on a 2018 Mac mini. I have an Akitio enclosure, connected to the Mac via a Thunderbolt 2<->3 adapter. At random, one of the drives in the enclosure becomes read-only (the other drives are fine). I'm not really sure where to begin troubleshooting this. This also happened on my 2013 Mac Pro running High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've already done this, but I would check my connectors.  Additionally, the one drive may not be getting as much power and/or can be beginning to fail.  If you have a way to test it externally on another device, I think we would learn a lot more about the cause.
I hope this provides some helpful ideas/thoughts.  Keep us posted!

Comment: Connectors seem fine. It happens only once in awhile, so it's difficult to test on another machine that I'm not able to get work done on. I ran First Aid in Disk Utility, everything came back OK.